# Get Maximum , Minimum , High of first bar and low of Last from Esper Query

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

I am new with Esper which is Javas Complex Event Processing framework. Currently i am using the following query:

```
select 
min(low) as minLow,max(high) as maxHigh
from 
Bar.win:time_batch(180 sec);
```

I also want to get the high of first Bar and Low of Last bar in 180 sec window. Any Idea how can i achieve that?

Comment: Ok I have found the solution... We can use last() and first().

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. That way other people can use it. And you might get upvoted. You can also accept your answer as the answer to the question and earn reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use last() and first().